# Have a command button as a part of output text

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have objects of  wrapper class in a list and in my Vf page i am checking if the object of the wrapper contains null, if it has null then i am displaying 'Free' else displaying the appointment details.

I want to have a button create Appointment instead of 'Free'.

What would the correct way to insert the button code ?

```
<apex:repeat var="slot" value="{!liTimeSlots}">

<tr class="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), 'Free', 'Fill')}">
    <td ><apex:outputText value="{!slot.tstart1}"/></td>

      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), 'Free', slot.sAppointment.name)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), '', slot.sAppointment.Appointment_Type__c)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), '', slot.sAppointment.Patient__c)}"/></td>
        </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td></td>

      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointmentOverlap), ' ', slot.sAppointmentOverlap.name)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointmentOverlap), '', slot.sAppointmentOverlap.Appointment_Type__c)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointmentOverlap), '', slot.sAppointmentOverlap.Patient__c)}"/></td>
        </tr>
```

**EDIT :**
Before i read the answers from mmmix and LaceySnr i implemented with use of css classes. not sure if this is the best way. But now the issue is of the param value not coming up on the controller method.

```
<apex:repeat var="slot" value="{!liTimeSlots}">

<tr class="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), 'Free', 'Fill')}">
    <td ><apex:outputText value="{!slot.tstart1}"/></td>

      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), 'Free', slot.sAppointment.name)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), '', slot.sAppointment.Appointment_Type__c)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), '', slot.sAppointment.Patient__c)}"/></td>
      <td><div Class="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), 'ShowButton', 'HideButton')}">
      <apex:commandButton action="{!Book}" Value="Book">
      <apex:param name="Timev" value="{!slot.tstart1}"/></apex:commandButton></div></td>
        </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td></td>

      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointmentOverlap), ' ', slot.sAppointmentOverlap.name)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointmentOverlap), '', slot.sAppointmentOverlap.Appointment_Type__c)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointmentOverlap), '', slot.sAppointmentOverlap.Patient__c)}"/></td>
        </tr>
```

```
public  PageReference Book()
{
String Timeval=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Timev');
system.debug('timeval +++++++++++++++'+Timeval) ;// This is returning null
pr=Page.Appointment;
pr.setRedirect(true);
pr.getParameters().put('App_start',Timeval);
pr.getParameters().put('App_start_Date',string.valueof(Appointment.Start_Date__c));

return pr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the thing about the button, but you also have an alternative way of doing !IF, for example:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!field}" rendered="{!condition"} />
```

If for button you are thinking about inserting apex:commands into a repeater and tie event handler to specific row, that can be done through parameters

for example I used this to crete a comamnd link in every table row:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Action">
    <apex:commandLink id="cmdDetachService" action="{!detachService}" value="Detach" rerender="mainBlock, errors" status="ajaxPostStatus" >
        <apex:param value="{!item.id}" name="activeService" />
    </apex:commandLink>
</apex:column>
```

Then in the event handler you can extract parameter from page parameters, for example `ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('activeService')`

Also, if you want to have if/then/else text/button rendering inside a td tag you can use this

```
<td>
    <apex:outputText .... rendered="{!condition"} />
    <apex:commandButton .... rendered="{!NOT(condition)"} />
</td>
```

Comment: thanks mmix.. but this solution would create a commandlink every line. if wanted to show only when slot.sAppointment is null. i also tried adding a param to command button. But i am not able to capture the param value in the controller.. its returning null. Updated the question.

Comment: sorry.. i understood what you meant by the use of rendered to get the conditional display. thanks for the tip

Comment: you have `rendered` attribute on commandButton as well, you don't need to play with styles to hide the button.

Comment: Thanks mmix, i would modify the code to use the rendered attribute.. Any idea on what is causing the param not getting passed to the controller method?

Comment: Its a string value in the list liTimeSlots, which is an list of a wrapper class. i am using this in my first TD. which is displaying correctly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7740/discussion-between-prady-and-mmix)

Comment: mmix, your suggestion on rerender did the trick.. thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest just using another mechanism for controlling the conditional rendering. `<apex:variable>` works well for this despite not being expressly designed for this purpose, for example, you could change:

```
<td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), 'Free', slot.sAppointment.name)}"/></td>
```

to:

```
<apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), true, false)}">
    <td><apex:commandButton action="{!someAction} value="Do This!"/></td>
</apex:variable>
<apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), false, true)}">
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!slot.sAppointment.name}"/></td>
</apex:variable>
```

Obviously in this case it's generated more code, but looking at the rest of this I think you could (with context) boil this down further to use just a couple of these tags and fewer `rendered` attributes.

Comment: wow.. this is neat... I got a result similar to what i needed using css. would you recommend using this method or the css one? My guess is this would be faster while rendering.. not sure on the processing

Comment: avoid using css to hide/show apex stuff. commands so and so, however if you have a required inputfield hiding it will not remove it from validation check.

Comment: As @mmix says, I'd avoid using CSS / Javascript where possible. Doing it this way means everything that should be transported in the view state will be.

Comment: @LaceySnr - isn't using an outputPanel with layout=none a slightly more "correct" approach?

Comment: @jkraybill I think so, but I learned about the var one first so tends to be the one that springs to mind :)